# Remove popup of registration of customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, popup, registration

I want to remove this popup but i don't know what to override and i can't debug when i clic create account this popup shows up. [image]

Comment: This, doesn't come out of the box in Magento. You must have installed some custom module for it. You need to just disable that.

Comment: yes i installed social login

Comment: ok thank you,  can you please  help me to know how to override this popup because i just added 2 custom attributes to the form registration but they don't appear here in this popup

Comment: you can either find a setting in Store configuation to diable it, or you may disable the module.

Comment: BTW, which module did you install??

Comment: Mageplaza Extensions Social Login

Comment: ok when i  set show popup to No even the login with Fb and Linkdin disappear so i had to override this popup not to remove it please any Idea

Comment: In that case, you will have to do some customization. You may dive into the code written in the extension and get rid of the popup, without losing the social login. or, you can try some other extension without popup

Comment: Welcome :) please upvote the answer if you found it helpful